# using imfuse in Matlab to alpha blend grayscale images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to overlay 2 gray scale images in Matlab using the imfuse function. In the "overlap" region, I'd like to take 50% of image A and 50% of image B. What I'm getting instead is the sum of A and B in the overlap region. This code demonstrates:

```
A = 50*ones(100,100);
A = padarray(A,[50 50],'both');
RA = imref2d(size(A));

B = 50*ones(100,100);
B = padarray(B,[100 100],'pre');
RB = imref2d(size(B));

[C,RC] = imfuse(A,RA,B,RB,'blend');

imshow(C,RC,[]);
```

[image]

Is there a way to control the blend parameters so I can get a 50/50 mix??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to just divide the overlapping areas by 2:

```
C(A~=0 & B~=0) = C(A~=0 & B~=0)./2;
```

This only works if zero exclusively marks padded areas. If a zero value exists in any image those pixels will not get averaged.